# How to cancel subsequent requests in axios interceptor?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, response, use-effect

I am working on a project in react with redux/redux-saga and a doubt arose. I am implementing with Axios in the response interceptor a way to logout the user when the session token has expired.

Basically, what I'm looking for is, to logout the user when calling to a private endpoint and it returns a 403. But I have this problem:

I have routes where I must do 3 dispatches (calls to different endpoints on the API) during the component loads which all 3 bring me relevant information to the components. Obviously, when the token is expired it will return 403, and the interceptor in the response will do the logout process to remove it from the session. However, even after doing the logout, the other 2 requests will also be called and there is no need cuz I already detected in the first call that the token expired.

```
  // EFFECTS
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAccountsInit("users"));
    dispatch(getAccountsInit("kash"));
    dispatch(getBanksInit());
    dispatch(getCurenciesInit());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

How do I prevent this? How do I cancel subsequent requests when detecting that the token has expired on the first one? .. I was looking for information about it but I couldn't find it. I thank you very much for the help.

Here is my response inteceptor

```
  export const resInterceptor = (instance) =>
  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    (error) => {
      const configRequest = error.config,
        status = error.status || error.response.status;

      console.warn("Error status: ", status || error.code);
      console.log(error);

      if (status === 418 && !configRequest._retry) {
        alert("Ha finalizado tu sesión, serás re dirigido y deberás iniciar sesión nuevamente.");
        store.dispatch(logoutSuccess());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume action creators like `getAccountsInit` are async thunks. In this meaning, you actually send 4 requests in parallel and once any of it gets 403, there is no use try stopping others. This way you can only try preventing of interceptor to call `logoutSuccess()` but is it really needed? I doubt.

You can refer to `store` inside interceptor in order to get current "logged in or not" status, but to me it seems as unnecessary complication.

You also can return `Promise` from your `getAccountsInit`, `getAccountsInit` etc and chain them:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAccountsInit("users"))
      .then(() => dispatch(getAccountsInit("kash")))
      .then(() => dispatch(getBanksInit()))
      .then(() => dispatch(getCurenciesInit()));
  }, [dispatch]);
```

But this way for "normal" flow(session has not expired) user will get ~4x longer loading(instead of running in parallel requests go in sequence).

TL;DR; just let it sending requests even if they may be useless due to session expiration; code complexity or slower loading is not worth it